# Adding a custom cell programmatically

Tags: objective-c

I have this UICollectionView, which I created programmatically.
Now, I would like to add it a custom cell that is a cell class I have created.

So the cell class called `GridCell.h/GridCell.m`, I now need to add it to my collectionView:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
self.GridView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
GridCell *cell = [[GridCell alloc] init]; //my cell

[self.GridView registerClass:cell forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; //not good !
[self.GridView setDelegate:self];
[self.GridView setDataSource:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.GridView];
```

Comment: And whats you problem? What is not working and/or what is the expected outcome in relation to the actual outcome?

Comment: @Pfitz If you knew the subject you would see my mistake right a way , and not make a stupid assumptions, see the answer of Martin, and learn from it.

Comment: Curnelious: You will not make much friends on SO with comments like that! - I happened to see the problem, but that does not change the fact that it is *your responsibility* to describe the problem clearly (for example: It does not compile with the following error message), and "not good !" is not a clear description. @Pfitz did not make any "stupid assumptions". He asked for clarification, which can be the first step to solve a problem.

Comment: @MartinR if he thinks that my question is not good he can ask for more details. this approach of people here to just down-vote any question they like,without any thinking,  like if they where some CEO's is not moral. as this site managers always said: be kind, oh yea, be kind only if you don't have 1000000 points here, and spend your life in this site, otherwise, you can do what ever you like, because you contribute enough to the pocket of this site managers . So much ego..wow..

Comment: @Curnelious I did not down vote and just asked a question to get more details since I did not directly spotted the problem. Sorry for trying to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register the cell's *class*, not an instance of the class:

```
[self.GridView registerClass:[GridCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```